# Is it possible and how to log a website internal connection activity?

Tags: logging, connections, vpn

For instance, I have developed a WordPress website and prepared to deploy to client's server. Since they request the site to be scanned in their VPN server first. For some reason, the application connects to many external resources and because the VPN is blocked the site from connecting to other location than its internal address, it is very slow. The slowness is believed to be due to blocking and retrial until giving up.

Since the application consists of a lot of plugins. What connection it is trying to make is not so obvious and straightforward.

Is it possible to track/log what the connection it is trying to made? If it is possible, I could do it in local server environment level and coding level to make a list of connection that it is trying to connect. And then I could use this list to discuss with the client and ask for white listing.

eg. normal connection log /user activity utility could log
user A with IP A visit > website.

But currently, if the site itself connect to

- wordpress.org <<< possible log it down?
- website B ...
- website C
- ...

Any hints, suggestions, insight is highly appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605584/how-can-i-inspect-page-resources-in-firefox#35985774  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605476/how-to-use-networks-waterfall-in-chrome-dev-tool-to-diagnose-web-rendering-perf#42637398  (ie look at a pages resources and show what is taking time to load)

Comment: This could only show 1 page at a time and could not show non-loading page. There are quite a no of pages including the backend have the issues. And that's probably showing client side loading only. For server side loading before feeding to browser or before rendering in chrome, it will not show the trace. In my cases, both sides logging is needed.